# Modifying toolbar's height in a ExtJS theme

Tags: extjs

I am starting a custom ExtJS 4 theme. And have a beginner question.

How can I increase the height of the toolbar?

I did some basic search, and found that we can do it in the app's [javascript code by modifying the toolbar's config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585132/reduce-the-height-of-a-titlebar-sencha)

However, I want that increase in toolbar height to be part of the theme. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the layout of the container that contains the toolbar, component layout could potentially rely on the JavaScript set height of the toolbar for positioning and layout calculation purposes.

I would highly recommend against setting a height in css in this case, although you could modify the css for the .x-toolbar class.

If you are expecting multiple toolbars throughout the UI to be the same height, I would recommend creating a new class that extends the toolbar, and set the default height of your new extended toolbar to be the height you want. Then when you create the items, use xtype: 'yourToolbar'.